# Jquery sort with comma separated value

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I want sort table using comma separated list

```
var list = 15,11,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,29,30,31,34,38,39,40;
```

My html table

```
<tr id="recordsArray_11"><td>11</td></tr>
<tr id="recordsArray_15"><td>15</td></tr>
<tr id="recordsArray_16"><td>16</td></tr>
```

How to display order form this list?

Comment: sort the array in jquery and then iterate over it. google for this! you will find plenty solutions

Comment: does list include all rows? If not what to do with others. Please show what you have tried

Comment: I dont have any code becouse i dont know where to start. Im read about jQuery sortable, check some sort plugin with no effect. This list include all rows.

Comment: Why this fiirst sort dont work http://jsfiddle.net/VjtYJ/83/

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = 15,11,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,29,30,31,34,38,39,40;
```

since your list is just a series of numbers at this point, it's still text  so enclose in single or double quotes when declaring.

only a single numeric var can be declared like that:var interest_rate=0.025;

```
var list = "15,11,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,29,30,31,34,38,39,40";
list = list.split(",");  // list is become list[]
list.sort()  //now sorted

var table=document.getElementById("my-table-name"); 
for(i=0,i<list.length;i++){
  var tr=document.createElement("tr");             
  var td=document.createElement("td");
  tr.id="recordsArray_"+list[i];
  td.value=list[i];
  tr.appendChild(td);
  table.appendChild(tr);
}
```